# How can I move this DataTemplate to a separate XAML file and keep the Command working on .NET MAUI?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, mobile, maui, syncfusion

I currently have a page with a Syncfusion control in a .NET MAUI application, this is the XAML:

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MyProject.SchedulePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:schedule="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Scheduler;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Scheduler"
    x:Name="schedulePage"
    Title="Agenda"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="{OnPlatform iOS='True',
                                       Default='False'}">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AppointmentTemplate">
            <StackLayout Background="MediumPurple">
                <Label
                    FontFamily="Bold"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Text="{Binding Subject}"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.AppointmentTappedCommand, Source={Reference professionalScheduler}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout>
        <schedule:SfScheduler
            x:Name="professionalScheduler"
            AllowViewNavigation="True"
            AppointmentsSource="{Binding Events}"
            DisplayDate="{Binding DisplayDate}"
            ShowNavigationArrows="False"
            ShowWeekNumber="False"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            View="Day">
            <schedule:SfScheduler.DaysView>
                <schedule:SchedulerDaysView
                    AppointmentTemplate="{StaticResource AppointmentTemplate}"
                    EndHour="22"
                    MinimumAppointmentDuration="0:30:0"
                    StartHour="8"
                    TimeFormat="HH:mm"
                    TimeRegions="{Binding Regions}" />
            </schedule:SfScheduler.DaysView>
        </schedule:SfScheduler>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class ScheduleViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<SchedulerAppointment> Events { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SchedulerAppointment>();

        public ICommand AppointmentTappedCommand { get; }

        public ScheduleViewModel(IAppointmentsService bookingsService)
        {
            AppointmentTappedCommand = new Command<SchedulerAppointment>(async (appointment) => await OnAppointmentTappedCommand(appointment));
        }

        private async Task OnAppointmentTappedCommand(SchedulerAppointment appointment)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Appointment", $"{appointment.Id} - {appointment.Subject} - {appointment.StartTime} - {appointment.EndTime}", "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

As it stands when I tap on a item on my scheduler I trigger the `AppointmentTappedCommand` on my `ViewModel` and see the `DisplayAlert`.

However when I try to move the `DataTemplate` to another file the template keeps working, the `Subject` is still bound correctly to the Data Context, but my `AppointmentTappedCommand` stops working. This is the XAML file with the DataTemplate:

```
<ContentView
    x:Class="MyProject.Templates.Scheduler.AppointmentTemplate"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="appointmentTemplate">
    <StackLayout Background="MediumPurple">
        <Label
            FontFamily="Bold"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="{Binding Subject}"
            TextColor="White"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.AppointmentTappedCommand, Source={Reference professionalScheduler}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

How can I keep the command working even when I have the template on another file?

Comment: Do you want a [```TemplateBinding```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0#bind-to-a-templated-parent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We suggest you use the Tapped event to achieve your requirement instead of the TapGestureRecognizer in the sample. Please refer to the following steps’How to use the Tapped event to command in the SfScheduler’.

Step1: Install the Community.Toolkit.Maui and add the UseMauiCommunityToolkit in MauiProgram.cs

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder.ConfigureSyncfusionCore();
    builder.UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkit();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Step 2: Add the command in the viewmodel

```
public ICommand AppointmentTappedCommand { get; set; }

public SchedulerViewModel()
{
    this.GenerateAppointments();
    this.DisplayDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(50);
    AppointmentTappedCommand = new Command<SchedulerTappedEventArgs>(async (appointment) => await OnAppointmentTappedCommand(appointment));
}

private async Task OnAppointmentTappedCommand(SchedulerTappedEventArgs obj)
{
    if (obj != null && obj.Element == SchedulerElement.Appointment && obj.Appointments[0] is SchedulerAppointment appointment)
    {
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Appointment", $"{appointment.Id} - {appointment.Subject} - {appointment.StartTime} - {appointment.EndTime}", "OK");
    }
}
```

Step 3: In MainPage.xaml

```
<scheduler:SfScheduler x:Name="Scheduler" 
                View="Week"
                DisplayDate="{Binding DisplayDate}"
                AppointmentsSource="{Binding Events}"
                AllowedViews="Day,Week,WorkWeek,Month,TimelineDay,TimelineWeek,TimelineWorkWeek,TimelineMonth">
    <scheduler:SfScheduler.DaysView>
        <scheduler:SchedulerDaysView>
        <scheduler:SchedulerDaysView.AppointmentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <local:AppointmentTemplate/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </scheduler:SchedulerDaysView.AppointmentTemplate>
    </scheduler:SchedulerDaysView>
</scheduler:SfScheduler.DaysView>
    <scheduler:SfScheduler.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
    EventName="Tapped"
    Command="{Binding AppointmentTappedCommand}" />
    </scheduler:SfScheduler.Behaviors>
</scheduler:SfScheduler>
```

Please let us know if you have any concerns.

Comment: The EventToCommandBehavior always gives me the SchedulerTappedEventArgs on the latest version of the CommunityToolkit. Even if I have values on the item tapped. I've also tried to add x:TypeArguments="SchedulerTappedEventArgs" on the EventToCommandBehavior but I keep getting a null argument.

Comment: I was able to pass the parameter using the EventArgsConverter property of the behavior on which I convert the SchedulerTappedEventArgs to an SchedullerAppointment.